# Using Pandas Groupby

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a `df` of crypto data and am trying to see if there is a particular time of the day/week when prices move one way or the other. I have the time stamp, day of the week and return from the previous time stamps close, as is the case in the example data below.

```
Date                  Day       Return
2019-06-22 01:00:00   Saturday -0.046910
2019-06-22 07:00:00   Saturday -0.018756
2019-06-22 13:00:00   Saturday  0.036842
2019-06-22 19:00:00   Saturday  0.000998
2019-06-23 01:00:00     Sunday  0.017672
2019-06-23 07:00:00     Sunday  0.021102
2019-06-23 13:00:00     Sunday -0.014737
2019-06-23 19:00:00     Sunday -0.039085
2019-06-24 01:00:00     Monday  0.009690
2019-06-24 07:00:00     Monday -0.004367
2019-06-24 13:00:00     Monday -0.005342
2019-06-24 19:00:00     Monday  0.001060
2019-06-25 01:00:00    Tuesday -0.027738
2019-06-25 07:00:00    Tuesday -0.001599
2019-06-25 13:00:00    Tuesday  0.006247
2019-06-25 19:00:00    Tuesday -0.036937
2019-06-26 01:00:00  Wednesday -0.064866
2019-06-26 07:00:00  Wednesday  0.012319
```

My first issue is the time stamp is confusing. As I get data from different exchanges the time stamp is different across a lot of them so I have abandoned the idea of trying to standardise the `Date` column and would now just like a new column that numbers the period in each day. So the first 6 hours in each saturday would be `Saturday_1` and so on. So in the end I would have 28 different categories (4 time periods x 7 days in the week).

What I would then like is to `groupby` this new column, and have returned to me the average return for each category as it were.

Cheers

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're asking for, the title refers to pandas groupby, but in the text body you seem to be struggling more with the date format. If you'd like help with the date format you'll have to provide examples each format. If you'd like help with group by can then you simply need to `means_by_period = df.groupby('period').Return.mean()`, which will return a series of 28 values indexed by the period.

Comment: Sorry fair comment, I guess I was thinking more about the end product, anyway Quang Hoang gave a great answer for the first half of the problem and yours was perfect for the second half so thanks very much both of you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your `Day` column is correct:

```
# ignore if already datetime
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)

# hour block in the day
s = df.Date.dt.hour//6 + 1

# new column
df['group'] = df['Day'] + '_' + s.astype(str)
```

output:

```
0      Saturday_1
1      Saturday_2
2      Saturday_3
3      Saturday_4
4        Sunday_1
5        Sunday_2
6        Sunday_3
7        Sunday_4
8        Monday_1
9        Monday_2
10       Monday_3
11       Monday_4
12      Tuesday_1
13      Tuesday_2
14      Tuesday_3
15      Tuesday_4
16    Wednesday_1
17    Wednesday_2
Name: group, dtype: object
```